# a function name slice which takes a string input and return the sliced string (like from 3 to 6)

Tags: arrays, c, slice

```
#include <stdio.h>

void slice(char user_input[]);

int main(){
    char user_input[100];
    scanf("%s", user_input);

    slice(user_input);
}

void slice(char user_input[]){
    char result[3];
    int n = 3, m = 6;
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; user_input[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (i >= 3 && i <= 6)
        {
            result[x] = user_input[i];
           x++;
       }
    
    }
    puts(result);   
}
```

try changing the length of the result array to 100 or 50 and see the output i didnt get it why is it showing some weird output

Comment: You forgot to put the null terminator into your sliced string and the `result` array is not large enough.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong/weird output you see is due to undefined behaviour because here is no null terminator in the `result` array and/or the `result` array is not long enough.

You want this:

```
void slice(char user_input[]) {
  char result[30];    // provide more space
  int n = 3, m = 6;
  int x = 0;

  for (int i = 0; user_input[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (i >= 3 && i <= 6)
    {
      result[x] = user_input[i];
      x++;
    }
  }

  result[x] = '\0';   // put the null terminator
  puts(result);
}
```

The explanation is in the comments.

---

But anyway this is overly complicated and inefficient.

This is better and simpler:

```
...
#include <string.h>  // neded for strcpy
...

void slice(char user_input[]) {
  char result[30];
  int n = 3, m = 6;
  
  strcpy(result, user_input + n, m - n);

  puts(result);
}
```

If you're not allowed to user `strcpy` for whatever reason (exercise etc.) you should write your own `strcpy` function, which is also ony 1-2 lines of code.

Be aware that there is no validation at all in this code, the `result` buffer might still be too small depending on the values of `n` and `m`.

---

**Disclaimer**

The overall design is still poor.

- The `slice` function should have `m` and `n` as parameters.
- If you are planning to modify `void slice` into `char *slice` (as your title *"... and return the sliced string "* suggests, this won't work if you naively add a `return result;` at the end as returning the address of a local variable will ultimately fail, there are numerous duplicates of this on stackoverflow.com).
- and a few other details as missing parameter validation etc.

Comment: yes, I know that the code is complicated and poorly designed. I have a habit of first doing the way it is easy as it makes it easy for me to get the correct way to do that avoiding confusion and then I try to make it more and more efficient thanks again to get into deep and explaining the pros and cons of my code 

Comment: please explain how you use this and why and why with multiple parameters strcpy(result, user_input + n, m - n);

Comment: @sarthakjain I don't get your latest comment. Did you read the documentation of `strcpy`? It's a very basic function. Did you read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book?